# What is the most elegant way to provide a cross-platform project with automated compilation routine?

Tags: compiling, latexmk, arara, makefile, rubber

There are many different ways to automate the compilation of a LaTeX project.

I would like to start a discussion, what would be the most flexible and elegant and omnipotent way to provide a project which is compilable quickly on all operation systems, in most programs and for all users.

The example scenario: I am uploading a "super complex project" to BitBucket or alike. I want to work on it on Linux and Windows. If others want to contribute something, they just have to read my `README.md` saying for example "Install `arara` and `make`, open `main.tex` in vim and run `:make` on Linux or `:! make` on Windows! Ready!"

---

I have not used rubber or latexmk but am keen to learn about. Please comment on that, if you like it.

---

My routine for now is:

Using arara in the `main.tex`

```
% arara: lualatex: { shell: yes }
% arara: biber
% arara: makeglossaries
% !arara: indent: { overwrite : yes, trace : yes, files: [ header.tex, main.tex, chapter/Foo.tex, chapter/Bar.tex] }
```

Edit this file in vim and run `:make` with the following `Makefile` (excerpt)

```
target = main

all: ararabuild

full: 
    ararabuild
    ararabuild
    ararabuild

ararabuild:
    arara --log --verbose $(target)

view: ararabuild viewonly

viewonly:
    evince $(target).pdf || AcroRd32.exe $(target).pdf

bib: 
    biber $(target)

%.pdf: %.tex
    ararabuild $<

clean:
    find . -name "*.log" | xargs rm -vf
    find . -name "*.aux" | xargs rm -vf
    find . -name "*.toc" | xargs rm -vf
    find . -name "*.blg" | xargs rm -vf
    find . -name "*.out" | xargs rm -vf
    find . -name "build" | xargs rm -vf
```

This runs good for me (except the cross-platform `view` stuff). But I just would like to see what techniques are around, what is best practice... or simple: How to get rid of all the configurations of different `LaTeX`-programs, the explanations of compiling routines and so on. Just imagine a `TeX`-template for a company. Much easier to provide if they just have to input their text using some familiar editor and then (for example) double click on some batch file...

I hope it is allowed to start such a discussion here. TeX automation tools are cool, but their use isn't that popular until now and cool using examples are still missing i.m.o.

Comment: Are we allowed to cheat and use two different tools? For example, for LaTeX3 development we use `make` on Unix but batch files on Windows. The batch files are called `make.bat`, so the interface is platform-independent.

Comment: Of course. I am using arara and make. Insert what ever you want into your project folder and write a "README.md for idiots".

Comment: I haven't had to write a latex build script after trying latexmk

Comment: It depends on what "super complex project" means.  For the case illustrated by your example, `latexmk` is an appropriate tool.  It automatically determines dependencies and the necessary number of repeated runs (of `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, or whatever).  All you do is run the command as `latexmk main`.  Since you use `lualatex` and `makeglossaries`, you'll need a `latexmrc` file to configure `latexmk` appropriately (it would be about 4 lines).  This is all platform independent.

Comment: You could use [lake](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Lake), which is a build engine written in Lua, with LuaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If you all don't mind, give a full working example. Doesn't has to be "super complex" but at least some `makeindex` or equal. Imagine you send this project to someone who is just used to press `pdflatex` in TeXnicCenter or alike. He should be able to compile without frustration and get the complete "complex" result you had in mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To allow convenient use of `latexmk` for making/building the project, put a file `latexmkrc` in the same directory is its primary source file `main.tex`.  For the project described in the question, appropriate contents of `latexmkrc` are

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$dvi_mode = $postscript_mode = 0;
$pdflatex = 'lualatex %O %S';
@default_files = ( 'main.tex' );
```

The first two lines simply tell `latexmk` to make a `.pdf` file instead of its default `.dvi`.  The third line configures `latexmk` to use `lualatex` instead of its default of `pdflatex`, since the question indicates that this is required by the project.  The fourth line specifies the name of the primary source file (taken from the question).

Then to do the compilation from the command line, the user should just change directory to the main directory of the project, and then run the command `latexmk`.  That will take care of running `lualatex`, `biber`, and `makeindex` as needed.  There is no need to specify any of the files on which the project depends other than `main.tex`; those dependencies are all determined by `latexmk`.

### Platform independence

`Latexmk` is installed by default in both the major distributions, TeXLive and MiKTeX.  It runs on all the major OSs.  Its only requirements are to have a correct `TeX` installation and to have `Perl` available.  `Perl` is installed by default on Linux and OS-X, and is included with the MS-Windows version of TeXLive.  But a user running MiKTeX on MS-Windows may need to install `Perl`.

### Glossaries

The question also indicated that the project uses glossaries.  In the `latexmk` distribution see http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles to find some examples of how to configure `latexmk` for special situations.  One of the examples covers the case of glossaries.

### Use with front ends

For a user who prefers not to use the command line from a terminal, front ends like TeXShop, TeXWorks, etc can be configured to use `latexmk`.  The user should consult the documentation for his/her preferred front end program and/or do the appropriate Google search.  Experts on each of these programs could add to this answer pointers to where these instructions are to be found.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was waiting for more interesting examples but the discussion is not getting in a roll... Therefore I mark your good answer as such.